# How do I check every value in a Java string?

Tags: java, string

If I had a string, say:

```
String name;
```

Is there a way I can check each letter with a loop? So if they enter a name can I check what each letter is?

Comment: Why? You can just use `System.out.println(name)`

Comment: Despite the number of answers, it's really not clear what you're asking here. I suggest you expand your question, what are you trying to do? Validate the string? Blacklist particular characters?

Answer (score 6):

There are several ways to do it - you can do a `for` loop with an index, or a `foreach` loop on the `char[]` array:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i != s.length() ; i++) {
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    ....
}

for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
    ....
}
```

In addition to checking each letter separately, you can check all letters at once (or any subset that you'd like) with [*regular expressions*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`String.toCharArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) function.

Answer (score 2):

```
char[] chars = name.toCharArray();
for (int i =0; i < chars.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println(chars[i]);
}
```

Comment: or `for(char ch: name.toCharArray())`

Answer (score 1):

This should do

```
for ( int i=0 ; i < name.length(); i++)
{
   name.charAt(i);
}
```

Also read this
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/manipstrings.html